# Check null value for timestamp in report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a DB table with the attribute of a `datetime` type, I described this attibute with a field of `java.sql.timestamp` type at my report.  I'm getting the error `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp` in case the field contains null instead of some value.

I tried to check for null value but it didn't work. This checking below only work if datatype from database is `string`. `$P{returnee_datetime} == null ? "" : $P{returnee_datetime}`

Right now the work around is by formating datetime to string at query `DATE_FORMAT(t1.returnee_datetime, '%d-%m-%Y') AS returnee_datetime`.

So how do I check timestamp for null value on iReport?

My template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="KEW.PA-9" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <parameter name="returnee_datetime" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="165">
            <elementGroup/>
            <textField pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="20" y="52" width="114" height="12"/>
                <box leftPadding="3"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{returnee_datetime} == null ? "" : $P{returnee_datetime}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: `I tried to check for null value but it didn't work` - You should post the small jrxml to reproduce the issue. The usage of a ternary operator is a good choice

Comment: @AlexK I include `jrxml ` code in my update above.

Comment: `<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{returnee_datetime} == null ? "" : $P{returnee_datetime}]]></textFieldExpression>` - You got the error because you are using `""` at the expression for showing value of `java.sql.Timestamp` (you can't cast String to Timestamp type).  For example, you can use null instead of empty string.

Comment: @AlexK I tried this `$P{returnee_datetime} == null ? null : $P{returnee_datetime}` still error if no data.

Comment: `still error if no data` - What error did you get?

Comment: @AlexK this error : `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp`

Comment: Are you testing the case with the jrxml you posted yesterday? Or with help of some other template?

Comment: @AlexK I use the same jrxml file I posted here.

Comment: The posted JRXML works well in Report Studio.   Unless for example iReport is passing the parameter as a String when you're attempting to run/preview the report.  The posted JRXML doesn't have your `queryString` so it must not be what you're actually using?

Comment: @kendavidson When no data it will error and I assume it because a string datatype is passed to the report.